# How to create binary tree using STL Set C++

Tags: visual-c++, data-structures, binary-tree

Can anyone tell me how to implement Binary tree using C++ STL set.

I have implemented binary tree using structures in C and class in C++

```
struct binary {
    int node;
    struct binary *left;
    struct binary *right;
};
```

I am not sure about how to implement it using STL set. Actually I don't know how to to represent **left and right** in set.

By the way, its not homework.

Comment: A `std::set` likely uses a binary tree internally to store its elements (a red-black tree or some variation thereof, most likely).  You don't usually implement your own binary tree using a `std::set`... can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is this homework?  The standard implementation for the `::std::set` type is a binary tree.

Comment: Its not a homework... I can implement binary tree in C using structures..

Answer (score 0):

`std::set` uses a binary (usually red-black) tree in its own implementation. You wouldn't want use it to implement a binary tree.